# HTML Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

```html
  <div class="main-menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">                                                  
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>                                
      </ul>
```

I'm struggling to create a very basic drop down menu using list items. Could anyone please tell me how I'd go about creating a drop down menu to the below:

```
  <div class="main-menu">
      <ul class="menu-list">                                                  
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>                                
      </ul>
```

I've no issues with CSS so styling shouldn't be a problem, but I', trying to achieve this without the use of Javascript.

Comment: hi, I think so too, not possible without Javascript. You need to bind a js function to an `onclick` event which changes some css in order to show/hide the menu.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay so could you tell me the simplest way to do this with minimal Javascript? I'm no expert on HTML or Javascript :/

Comment: @VaibhavVishal & @BobVandevliet it is possible without Javascript, using `checkbox` or `:hover` for example.

Comment: @DanAnderton You can find a lot of examples of dropdown menu on internet, did you search for some tutorials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible without JS, by setting your dropdown's nested options to display none, and then to flex or block them upon hovering their parent.  Here's a simple example using your code:

https://codepen.io/ehavener/pen/gBLOXV

HTML

```
 <div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">                 
     <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>   
   </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.main-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

.main-menu ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #21263E;
}

.main-menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there are some links for your answer.

1. Without CSS [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select
2. With CSS  [2]: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

If those bother you, there is the simplest solution.

I suppose you have no problem with your CSS though designing a drop down is pretty bang!

Inside Body tag: type those:

```html
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
```

This may work as your need.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use <div> you must need CSS to work without JS.

If you use <select>, there is no need of extra CSS or JS either