# How to use z-index in CSS to bring div to the front of another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a dropdown in CSS. I have finished writing the CSS code, but the dropdown pushes all my other objects on the screen down and that is not what I want. Instead, I want to show the dropdown in **front** of the objects instead at the top "which would end up pushing then down".

[image]

```
<div class="drop-down-container">
    <h1>Recommended</h1>
    <div class="dropdown-content-background">
        <div class="dropdown-contents">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <i class="material-icons">videocam</i>
                <span>Create</span>
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                 <span>Settings</span>
             </div>
             <div class="dropdown-content">
                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                <span>Switch Account</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.drop-down-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.dropdown-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content-background{
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 4px;

}

.dropdown-content i {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content span {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: One way to do this might be using a `fixed` position, like navigation bars. `position:fixed`. for the `div` that you want to be on top of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here [HTML Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690049/html-drop-down-menu) and here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar .

Use position: relative in your menu title then position:absolute in the dropdown container. This takes the element out of the flow of the html and stops it from pushing down the rest of the content. See below

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  padding: 0.125rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.menu:hover .drop-down-container {
  display: flex;
}

.drop-down-container {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.25rem;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content-background {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.dropdown-content i {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content span {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="menu">
    Hover for drop down
    <div class="drop-down-container">
      <div class="dropdown-content-background">
        <div class="dropdown-contents">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <i class="material-icons">videocam</i>
            <span>Create</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
            <span>Settings</span>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <i class="material-icons">person</i>
            <span>Switch Account</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>Some text here that's not being moved down by the menu
```

Comment: Thanks hat solved it for me